# strtok program crashing

Tags: c, strtok

the program for strtok given on http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html
crashes everytime..

```
#include <string.h>
...
char *token;
char *line = "LINE TO BE SEPARATED";
char *search = " ";


/* Token will point to "LINE". */
token = strtok(line, search);


/* Token will point to "TO". */
token = strtok(NULL, search);
```

If I use a char array for variable 'line', it works.
i.e. char line[] = "LINE TO BE SEPARATED" works.

Kindly explain.

Comment: Why does this have a `C++` tag? It's pure C code. `<string.h>` and `::strtok()` don't even exist in C++. (It's `<cstring>` and `std::strtok()`.) If you want to do this in C++, use `std::string` and streams (or any library providing tokenization).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strtok` modifies the input string `line`.

```
char *line = "LINE TO BE SEPARATED";
```

In this case `line` points to the read-only memory. Hence, cannot be modified. You need to pass char array for `strtok`.

Comment: Why doesn't C force `const char*` for this type of initialization? Also note `char line[] = "LINE TO BE SEPARATED";` works fine.

Comment: @NateS `char line[]` is a modifiable array that is just _initialized_ to contain the string initially, that's why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since this has a C++ tag:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::istringstream iss("LINE TO BE SEPARATED");
  while( iss.good() ) {
    std::string token;
    iss >> token;
    std::cout << token '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

***Edit:*** As Konrad said in his comment, the above loop could be replaced by `std::copy` working on stream iterators:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::istringstream iss("LINE TO BE SEPARATED");
  std::copy( std::istream_iterator<string>(std::iss)
           , std::istream_iterator<string>()
           , std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout, "\n") );
  return 0;
}
```

I have to (grudgingly) admit that there's something to be said for it.

Comment: I smell a `std::copy` here … ;-)

Comment: add `#include <iostream>` and replace the `'\n'` with `<< std::endl`

Comment: @Konrad: I can kind of guess what you're hinting at, but this `std::copy` idiom just never really appealed to me.

Comment: @James: I added the `<iostream>`, but I don't see a reason to flush `std::cout`'s buffer for every token, so I left it at `'\n'`.

Comment: @sbi: Huh? One statement in place of a loop with four statements. Granted, it’s longer but then C++ sucking at syntax is no news. Let me see if I get this right: `copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));`.

Comment: @Konrad: I hadn't claimed my dislike to be rational. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

`char *line` is a pointer and you are pointing it to a constant string (`"LINE TO BE SEPARATED"`). This fails when `strtok` attempts to modify that string. It would be better to qualify this variable as `const char *line`—still wouldn't work, but might lead to a helpful warning when you try to pass it to `strtok`.

Meanwhile the array `char line[]` can be modified (it's not `const`) and is only initialised to contain the string.

Answer (score 1):

aJ said what is needed. My advice is avoid that ugly & unsafe strtok. You are using C++ so go ahead with std::string. You also can use Boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/libraries.htm#String & http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo.html . If you want a new string class, you may look at http://bstring.sourceforge.net/ .