# srtok is not working in c

Tags: c, string, strtok, string-literals

here is my code,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
    explode (" ", "this is a text");
}

    explode (char *delimiter, char string[])
{
char *pch;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",string);
pch = strtok (string,delimiter);
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
}
return 0;
}
```

I compile this code using `gcc -o 1.exe 1.c` and shows no error. But when i execute `1.exe` it shows `Splitting string "this is a text" into tokens:` and at that moment `1.exe` stops working (a dialogue box of windows shows). can anybody tell the problem and solve the problem? I am using windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strtok giving Segmentation Fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385697/strtok-giving-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843236/strtok-program-crashing.

Comment: This code is awful! Please read a modern C book how to declare a function properly and format source code.

Comment: I've seen many examples of bad code, but this is a serious candidate to the top positions in this ranking. Please, rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't do this with strtok because the literal can't be modified, it can be done with strcspn.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void explode (char *delimiter, char *string);

int main()
{
    explode (" ", "this is a text");
    return 0;
}

void explode (char *delimiter, char *string)
{
    int span = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int length = 0;

    if ( delimiter && string) {
        length = strlen ( string);
        printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",string);
        while (offset < length) {
            span = strcspn ( &string[offset],delimiter);//work from offset to find next delimiter
            printf ("%.*s\n",span, &string[offset]);//print span number of characters
            offset += span + 1;// increment offset by span and one characters
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `explode()` function, you're passing a *string liteal* (`"this is a text"`) and using the same as the input to `strtok()`.

As `strtok()` modifies the input string, here, it will invoke invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). As mentioned in th `C11` standard, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You can either

- Define an array and initalize it with the *string literal* and the use the array as input to `strtok()`.
- take a pointer, use `strdup()` to copy the initializer and then supply that pointer to `strtok()`.

The bottom line is, the input string to `strtok()` should be modifiable.